# How to add horizontal, strecthed curly brace to plot?

Tags: plotting

I would like to refer to certain ranges of the x axis with the help of of some appropriately stretched and placed curly braces. I cannot figure out how to place a appropriately rotated and stretched curly brace in a plot.

Answer (score 3):

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
 Prolog -> Inset[First@ImportString@ExportString[︸, "PDF"], 
  {2 Pi - 0.05, 0}, Left, {Pi + 0.15, 2}]]
```

> [image: Plot]

Comment: There is also an [OverBrace](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/OverBrace.html) (`︷`).